# Does Eckmann-Hilton give a characterization of categories of algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

The Eckmann-Hilton argument shows that if $\mathcal{S}$ is a symmetric monoidal category, there is a monoidal equivalence

$$Alg(Alg(\mathcal{S})) \cong Alg^{co}(\mathcal{S})$$

between the symmetric monoidal category of algebras over algebras over $\mathcal{S}$ and commutative algebras over $\mathcal{S}$. Its then not hard to see that if $\mathcal{M} = Alg(\mathcal{S})$ we have $$Alg(\mathcal{M}) \cong Alg^{co}(\mathcal{M}).$$ I'm curious if this property characterizes categories of algebras. In other words if $\mathcal{M}$ is a symmetric monoidal category does a monoidal equivalence $Alg(\mathcal{M}) \cong Alg^{co}(\mathcal{M})$ imply that there exists a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{S}$ with $\mathcal{M} \cong Alg(\mathcal{S})$?

A characterization of categories of *commutative* algebras along these lines is easy, since Eckamnn-Hilton quickly shows that $$\mathcal{M} \cong Alg^{co}(\mathcal{S}) \text{ for some } \mathcal{S} \iff \mathcal{M} \cong Alg(\mathcal{M}).$$

So categories of commutative algebras are precisely those symmetric monoidal categories that are equivalent to the category of algebras over themselves. However, I don't think any such simple argument exists for non-commutative algebras. Any ideas or relevant literature would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m used to “algebra” referring to algebra categories of monads. What is an algebra for a symmetric mono ideal category? Do you mean a monoid?

Comment: Yes exactly, I suppose I should use the more standard terminology, but I usually work in the abelian context where i think this terminology is not too uncommon

Comment: Superscript co is very unusual notation for commutative...

Comment: So rephrasing the question (correct me if I'm wrong): Let $M$ be a symmetric monoidal category. If every monoid in $M$ is commutative, is $M$ itself a category of monoids? (i.e. is $M$ equivalent to the category of monoids in some  symmetric monoidal category $S$?)

Comment: @AlexKruckman exactly :)